# Understanding ActionForm

Tags: java, struts

I have just started learning struts. Most of the tutorials I read, it mentions capturing data using an ActionForm. ie. Performing a http post request with a form filled with data.

However, upon the initial loading of the form, populating of the dropdown boxes etc. How should I retrieve the data and populate to the view?

1. By saving the ArrayList to the request attribute and iterate it on the jsp.
2. Setting the ArrayList to a corresponding string[] array in the ActionForm.

Which is the correct / better implementation approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Action` class you can fetch the data using services and store it in a `List` which is a property of a `Form`

Comment: In another words, both the transfer of data from view to database, and database to view will both by transfer using the ActionForm? 


I have J2EE / Servlets background.

Comment: For example, a typical edit form screen. I have to retrieve the data from the database (create pojo) and transfer these pojo to the ActionForm required?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Use the ActionForm
- Use scoped attribute(s) (generally request)

I prefer to use the `ActionForm` only for form input data, but there are just as many people that say it should be used for anything in the form, including drop-down values.

(Some say it should be used for everything on a page, but they're clearly mad.)

Keeping data out of `ActionForm`s reduces framework coupling. This may make a transition to a modern framework that expects data to live in scoped attributes, either free-form or in a model object.